# Why I am not getting proper output in this code?

Tags: python

```
def kruskals():
   matrix = []
   total = 0
   min = 999
   u = 0
   v = 0
   parent = [None]*8
   noOfEdges = 1

   for i in range(0,7):
       parent[i] = 0
       for j in range(0,7):
           with open('input.txt') as file:
              for line in file:
                matrix.append([int(val) for val in line.split()])
                #print matrix
                if matrix[i][j]== 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = 999
   while (noOfEdges < 7 ):

      min = 999
      for  i in range(0,7):
            for j in range(0,7):
                    if min > matrix[i][j]:
                        min = matrix[i][j]
                        a = u = i
                        b = v = j
      while (parent[u] != 0):
        u = parent[u]

      while (parent[v] != 0):
        v = parent[v]

      if(v != u):
        noOfEdges = noOfEdges + 1
        print("edge found :{}->{}:{}".format(a,b,min))
        total = total + min
        parent[v] = u
      matrix[u][v] = 999
      matrix[v][u] = 999
    print("The weight of minimum spanning tree is : {}".format(total))
    return
    f.close()

kruskals()
```

I have written kruskals algorithm in python.I am taking inputs from text     file named 'input.txt'. The problem is that I am getting proper values till certain point, after that the output is not coming.Why is that so?

**input:**

'input.txt':

```
   0 28 999 999 999 10 999

   28 0 16 999 999 999 14

   999 16 0 12 999 999 999

   999 999 12 0 22 999 18

   999 999 999 22 0 25 24

   10 999 999 999 25 0 999

   999 14 999 18 24 999 999
```

**output :( till it displays properly)**

```
   edge found :0->5:10

   edge found :2->3:12

   edge found :1->6:14

   edge found :1->2:16
```

After this the output is not displaying."

Comment: How about you try some debugging yourself first? Now is a good time to learn basic debugging skills...

Comment: You're appending the entire file to the same matrix 49 times... Open the file, and then loop over rows and columns

Comment: @cwall There are 7 values in the range `(0, 7]` the end is not inclusive. Similarly, `range(7)` loops seven times

Comment: D'oh. Comment withdrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is running forever on the 6->3 edge (which won't ever be printed, since it's not needed in the spanning tree). That edge never gets cleared in `matrix`.  Your algorithm is supposed to clear every edge it checks, but these lines have an error:

```
  matrix[u][v] = 999
  matrix[v][u] = 999
```

They should be using the indexes `a` and `b`, rather than `u` and `v`.

As [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) commented, you also have an issue relating to the creation of `matrix`, though as it happens, that issue is unrelated to the issue you were asking about. You're currently adding a *lot* of extra copies of your data to `matrix`, since you've put the loop to read from the file inside a nested loop that sets `0`'s to `999`. I'm pretty sure you want to only read the file once, rather than 49 times.

Move these lines up and out of the loops they're in:

```
       with open('input.txt') as file:
          for line in file:
            matrix.append([int(val) for val in line.split()])
```